# Document paragraph spacing changes

Tags: spacing, paragraphs

I'm a bit confused about the paragraph spacing in my large document. To begin with my document has spaces between the paragraphs, which looks nice. However about halfway through it changes to no spacing, no indentation, which is inconsistent. I had a look online and have tried using `\usepackage{parskip}`, which made no difference.

I've narrowed down where the spacing changes to the following:

```
\captionof{figure}{Title}
\begin{center}
\underline{\textbf{Title of Document}}
\begin{enumerate}
\item item 1
\item Item 2
\end{enumerate}
\end{center}
```

I've tried getting rid of `\captionof...` with no luck. Any ideas much appreciated, thank you.

Apologies for not putting a working example, here is one:

```
\documentclass[11pt,openright,a4paper]{report}
\include{DissertationDefs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{parskip}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter One}
Normal paragraph spacing here, all seems to be ok.

There's a gap between here and above.

\captionof{figure}{Title}
\begin{center}
\underline{\textbf{Title of Document}}
\begin{enumerate}
\item item 1
\item Item 2
\end{enumerate}
\end{center}

Paragraphs now have no spacing.

Directly below.

\end{document}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Both `\begin{center}...\end{center}` and `\begin{enumerate}...\end{enumerate}` do change the spacings as long the the environments are *alive*.

Comment: Use `\centering` instead

Comment: I've now posted an example that is minimal and displays what I am experiencing for me. I don't think I've missed any `\end...` so not sure if that's the issue.

Comment: `\end{documentclass}` ???? Where have you seen this? ;-)

Comment: That's a mistake I made quickly adding an example, sorry. Removing it doesn't fix the issue. Changing to \centering doesn't make a difference.

Comment: What is the use of `\captionof...` there? There is no figure at at all

Comment: I have modified a word document to be included and wanted to give it a caption to show that it is a separate document, I chose figure as I wasn't sure if any options were relevant. I'm a beginner!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are some issues here, but I focused on the spacing stuff...

- Two lines of text, separated with an empty line --> LaTeX will start a new paragraph
- `\captionof` adds some vertical spacing above and below to prevent the caption to be to near to the figure/table
- `\begin{center}...\end{center}` introduces additional spacing.

If all of this should not affect later text the effect must be limited within a `\begingroup...\endgroup` pair.

---

```
\documentclass[11pt,openright,a4paper]{report}
\include{DissertationDefs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{parskip}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter One}
Normal paragraph spacing here, all seems to be ok.\newline
There's a gap between here and above.

%\begin{center}
\begingroup
\centering
\captionof{figure}{Title}
\underline{\textbf{Title of Document}}
\begin{enumerate}
\item item 1
\item Item 2
\end{enumerate}
\endgroup

%\end{center}


Paragraphs now have spacing.

Directly below.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I'm a bit confused because the preview doesn't seem to match the latex code? In the preview it says "Paragraphs now have spacing" but the code shows "Paragraphs now have no spacing"?

Comment: @Coolmurr: Sorry, I changed the preview code after I posted the code.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense now. Just in case anyone else has a look - I found moving the `\captionof{...}` to under the `\begin{center}` seemed to also work.

Comment: i think the question noted that the widely spaced paragraph at the beginning was desirable.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: Unclear, but anyway, I thought it's better to show the meanings/ways of LaTeX ;-)